# CentOs partitioning order

Tags: linux, centos

I am creating VM with CentsOS 6.9 . I have defined partitioning order in my script as below

> part /boot --fstype ext3 --size=100 --ondisk=xvda 
>   part / --fstype ext3 --size=1024 --grow --ondisk=xvda 
>   part swap --fstype swap --size=612 --ondisk=xvda

but after installation its changing sequence order as below

[image]

I was expecting root partition should be second and swap should be third . But after installation sequence of swap and root partition is getting changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `--onpart` in order to force it on a partition,

```
 part swap --fstype swap --size=612 --ondisk=xvda --onpart=xvda3
```

See here for more information:
   https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a valid explanation for it but looking your output, it looks like lsblk is not displaying the right order

For sure you have already read this article (it does not solve actually your issue)

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=218615

What if you try to list the partitions with fdisk -l and see if the order is the same?